# Detect if some material is covered in the current slide

Tags: beamer, hyperref

The question is:

*How to write a macro for **beamer** `\coveredIfTF{true code}{false code}` that tests whether the 'currently executed' part of the document is going to be displayed or not.*

Indeed, a beamer frame is executed potentially several times; each time a different slide has to be produced. In the case of a, e.g., `\uncover<3->{content}` commands, `content` is executed at each iteration (including internal commands that have side effects), but displayed only from the third slide onward. If occurring in `content`, `\coveredIfTF{true code}{false code}` would execute the `false code` for the two first slides, and the `true code` from the third slide onward.

The context is the development of the [knowledge](https://ctan.org/pkg/knowledge) package. The kind of things that we would like is be able to write (this code is incomplete):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\intro[1]{---suitable code---}
\newcommand\kl[1]{---suitable code---}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item A \intro{duck} is a \dots
\item A \intro{cat} is a \dots
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame} 
Take a \kl{duck}, \dots{}
Consider now a \kl{cat}, \dots
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

and the expected result would be the result of the compilation of the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item A \hypertarget<.>{duck}{duck} is a \dots
\item A \hypertarget<.>{cat}{cat} is a \dots
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame} 
Take a \hyperlink{duck}{duck}, \dots{}
Consider now a \hyperlink{cat}{cat}, \dots
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

The effect of `\intro` would be to add a target to the slide of the first time `\intro` is going to be **displayed** (hence the question having a macro `\coveredIfTF` which cleanly isolates this issue), and `\kl` hides a link to this target.

However, simple solution such as:

```
\newcommand\intro[1]{\hypertarget<.>{#1}{#1}}
```

is not satisfactory for several reasons.

- it does not work in other situations of **beamer**, for instance

  `\begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> A \intro{duck} is a \dots
  \item<2-> A \intro{cat} is a \dots
  \end{itemize}`
   This seems to arise because te `<.>` notation is tailored for working with `<+->`.
- I need a fine grained control of the macro in order to integrate it with the present and future functionalities of the knowledge package.
- Because this is for a package development and not for a single document, the solution has to be robust and be compatible with all the ways **beamer** has to deal with hiding and showing material.
- For the same reason, a solution in which the slide numbers are explicitly provided by the user is not acceptable.

Hence, for me, the best way to solve this problem would be to have a `\coveredIfTF{true code}{false code}` macro. And I would be ready to believe that such a macro internally already exist in **beamer**.

Comment: I have the feeling this is an XY-problem (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean). If you would add your real use-case, maybe there is a better workaround.

Comment: @samcarter I am developing the knowledge package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/knowledge) and have been requested to make it compatible with beamer. 

For making it simple, one can use a command `\intro{name}` that creates a link to the position of `\intro` in order to have the other uses  of 'name' point to this target. In beamer `\intro{name}` can be used in some slide without extra information, and the hyperlinks should be to the first (or last) uncovered instance of '\intro{name}': i.e. some slide in the middle of the frame. For this, `\intro` should be aware of the covering status.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project! Can you make a short example?

Comment: @samcarter An exemple would look like that (sorry for the display):

`\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1->   A \intro{rabbit} is \dots
\item<2->   A \intro{dog} is \dots
\item<3->   A \intro{cat} is \dots
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
A \kl{rabbit} points to slide 1,
a \kl{dog} points to slide 2,
and a \kl{cat} points to slide 3.
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem can be simplified to setting an hypertarget to the current slide. This way the links will jump to the correct overlay.

Unfortunately the code fragment you shared in [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399093/detect-if-material-covered-in-the-current-overlay/399109#comment993158_399093) did not produce any links (after adding `\usepackage{knowledge}`), so here a short example using normal hyperref commands:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
\hypertarget<.->{duck}{duck} 

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item \hypertarget<.->{rabbit}{rabbit} 
\item \hypertarget<.->{dog}{dog} 
\item \hypertarget<.->{cat}{cat} 
\end{itemize} 

\end{frame} 

\begin{frame} 
\hyperlink{duck}{duck}  

\hyperlink{rabbit}{rabbit}  

\hyperlink{dog}{dog} 

\hyperlink{cat}{cat} 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But these two solutions have hardcoded the number of the slides, so it is not a test usable in any situation.

Comment: @ThomasColcombet That's why the real use case would be interesting to find a better workaround.

Comment: Sorry for the code: it was not intended to compile, but just to make clear what I am looking for. However the above code you suggest causes warnings of identifier definitions with same names. And also it does not allow me to gather all the pieces of informations that are needed: the code I intend to work has to know when it is displayed in order to trigger specific code.

Comment: The above code compiles without warnings for me using pdflatex from texlive 2017. Can't you just trigger your `specific code` on the current slide, using some combination of `\only` or `\alt`?

Comment: Thanks  a lot. My version is also 2017 and recently updated. I obtain __l.13 \end{frame} pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{rabbit}) has been already used, duplicate ignored__.
Furthermore, I am looking for a code that works in **any context**, **without any twicking of the user**. For example a solution such as `\only<.->{code triggered only if visible}` works in the context of `\begin{itemize}<+->`, but does not when the equivalent syntax `\begin{itemize}\item<1-> ... \item<2-> ...` is used. Hence, that does not yet suit my needs.

Comment: @ThomasColcombet `\begin{itemize}[<+->]` and `\begin{itemize}\item<1-> ... \item<2-> ...` are the same. Triggering something on the current overlay should in principle always work, unless someone is deliberately messing with the `\beamer@slideinframe` counter. I am using `beamer 2017/08/22 v3.43`

Comment: this seems not to be true: consider for instance the code `\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item \only<.>{a} 
\end{itemize} 
`, does display an `a`while `\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> \only<.>{a} 
\end{itemize} 
` doesn't. I would like the code answering the question to not be dependent on such variations...